# Full Duplex RS485 recommendations

Tags: rs485

I am looking at a few IC's for full-duplex RS485 communication.

Are there any recommendations?

The current options I am looking at are:

- [SP490](http://www.exar.com/common/content/document.ashx?id=1337&languageid=1033)
- [SN75179](http://www.ti.com/product/sn75179b)
- [LTC490](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC490)

The first two are well priced for my project but I am just interested in what other people are using.

**Added details:**

The project is for hobby use only. It will connect 2 Atmel MCU's via UART that can be between 1-10 meters apart. I opted for Full-Duplex RS485, allowing users to connect the two units without any firmware changes.(3rd party firmware involved that I would like to interface to but can't make changes to)

The ADM2582 has a bunch of extra features that are on my wish list but its price puts it out of reach as I will need at least 2 units.

Comment: I think full duplex RS485 doesn't make sense since the Rx and Tx share the wire. By its nature, it's half-duplex. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)

Comment: Is it RS422, then?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the ADM2582 because it is an isolating type, has the voltage generator inside and can be run 2 wire or 4 wire: -

[image]

If anyone says that these are expensive (+£5 each) I say I don't give a damn because performance comes first on some parts of any job!

Also I'd like to point out that many folk do use full duplex RS485 because it's far easier conceptually to build repeaters on long line lengths. You can use two chips like the above (or non-isolating type) and wire them back to back. You can always convert to 2 wire at one end should that be necessary.

Comment: It's the isolation that makes this IC expensive.  There are probably non-isolated alternatives.

Comment: @scott I think the 2482 is cheaper and there's a lower speed 87 version but yes, ADI aren't going to be the cheaper end of the market in all things!

Comment: Yes, use them religiously myself for tranceivers and isolators.

Comment: Yes. It takes an awful lot of 5 quid bits to pay for a few field service calls.